# Left center and right center in python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to align my squares as in the image attached[image: Squares]. I have tried multiple things but I am unable to do so.

here is what I have so far

```
print(turtle.pos())
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.right(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

I am new to using turtle and have looked through the tutorials online but have not been able to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `right` to `left`, it will print the image you want.

You may need to set `heading(90)` first, depending which direction your turtle starts with.

Answer (score 0):

Start with

```
turtle.setheading(180)
```

Then your code will draw the small square correctly.  After you have drawn the small square, insert

```
turtle.right(180)
```

before drawing the large square, and your code will work.